# Branching Externals and Trunk together

Tags: svn, tags, branch, externals

I have' ExternalFolder' and 'trunk'in my SVN.
'trunk' has an empty folder linked to ExternalFolder (as written below).
I want to create a script that will take branch the trunk, tag (or branch) the ExternalFolder and connect the 'externals' in the newly branched trunk and connect it to the newly tagged ExternalFolder as in the following example:

- trunk

  - Project1

    - Externals (linked to *ExternalsFolder*)
- *ExternalsFolder*
- Branches

  - Project1_BranchA

    - TaggedExternalsFolder
    - Project1

      - Externals (linked to Project1_BranchA\TaggedExternalsFolder)

If this is complicated to achieve, I can also have the new tagged or branched 'ExternalFolder' to be located in a different location. Putting them both in the same dir is just for ease of access.
Is there an easy way to achieve this?
Do I need to write a script?

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem than yours. I solved it with a python script using [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) that :

1. grab recursively all the externals of my project
2. freeze each external, explicitly set the revision in the external property (easier than creating a branch/tag for each external)
3. then create the tag or branch